# Issue in Excel sub to import Fixed Width Text file with non-ASCII characters

Tags: excel, vba, non-ascii-characters

I have a sub to import a fixed width text file into excel, and this works fine if the file only has ASCII characters, but it does not work when the file has non-ASCII characters.  The file has character encoding of UTF-8.  When there are non-ASCII characters, they are imported as if they are multiple characters, so data in columns to the right are not imported correctly.  How can I import a fixed width file correctly if it may have non-ascii characters?  Originally I had all the fields as xlGeneralFormat, I tried changing the fields which may have non-ascii characters to xlTextFormat, but that did not affect the issue at all.

```
Sub ImportFixedWidth()
    Application.Workbooks.OpenText _
        Filename:="C:\Temp\Ok File.txt", _
        StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array( _
        Array(0, xlTextFormat), _
        Array(5, xlTextFormat), _
        Array(10, xlGeneralFormat), _
        Array(17, xlGeneralFormat))
End Sub
```

If I change the file, so the sub is:

```
Sub ImportFixedWidth()
    Application.Workbooks.OpenText _
        Filename:="C:\Temp\Issue File.txt", _
        StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array( _
        Array(0, xlTextFormat), _
        Array(5, xlTextFormat), _
        Array(10, xlGeneralFormat), _
        Array(17, xlGeneralFormat))
End Sub
```

Ok File.txt:

```
Text1Text2Number1Number2
applepear 1      2
Foo  Bar  3      4
Jane John 4      6
```

[image]

Issue File.txt

```
Text1Text2Number1Number2
applÉpÉar 1      2
Foo  Bar  3      4
Jane John 4      6
```

[image]

The expected Excel is:

[image]

Comment: What is the character encoding of the text file? That is required metadata for any attempt to convert bytes to text. (Excel's import wizard calls it "File Origin", which is equally helpful and confusing.)

Comment: I edited the question to indicate the character encoding is UTF-8.  I see based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.opentext?view=excel-pia that the Origin input you referred to should be the way to make this work.  It looks like based on recording a macro that for this I should specify a value of 65001, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, 65001 is UTF-8. I'm not familiar with that VBA function. "It should work."

Comment: I tested this with my data and it works.  If you want to make it an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.